# How does the accept answer on Stack Overflow work?

Tags: discussion

Is it that only the author of the question/post can accept the answer?

Also, how do others know that an answer is accepted?

Comment: You skipped the tour, didn't you?

Comment: [tour] [help] [ask] <- Read these. All of them.

Answer (score 0):

Only the author of the question can accept an answer and once you accept one, other people will know because there will be a green check mark next to the one you chose as correct. Please go look up some questions people asked to see how they asked them. Don't skip the tour either, it helps.